# Mesh Extra Objects - operator panel is empty when using api instead of gui

Tags: python, add-on

I am using the [Add Mesh Extra Objects](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_Mesh_Extra_Objects) Add-on.

If I add a regular solid via gui I can set stuff in the operator panel like source, size, vertex truncation, ...

If I use `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_solid_add()` (which should do the same, I see the api-call in the info-window at the top which is normally hidden) the operator panel stays empty.

How can I use `bpy.ops.mesh.primitve_solid_add()` and get the right operator panel contents.

Thanks